# Finding averages of subtotals in pivot tables

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am currently working with a pivot table that contains hours logged by individual people for specific tasks and I'm trying to find out the average time taken in man hours for a specific task types but I'm having a lot of difficultly finding a way to easily do it with large amounts of data. Essentially the current format of the data is like this:

```
Row Labels________________________________________________________________Totals

>Task Type - Service____________________________________________________________100
>>Task Number - 12345_________________________________________________________75
>>>Person A________________________________________________________________50
>>>Person B________________________________________________________________25

>>Task Number - 12346_________________________________________________________25
>>>Person C________________________________________________________________25

>Task Type - Manufacture_________________________________________________________50
>>Task Number - 00001_________________________________________________________50
>>Person D_________________________________________________________________50
```

The desired output is to have instead of the total 100 displayed, an average of the 2 totals in the child row "task number" would be displayed. Does anyone know of a way to do this that would be easily applicable to large amount of data?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, there is a relatively simple solution to this problem. If you go into your pivot table fields window, in your "Values" fields, click whatever your values is (I assume something along the lines of "hours"), and click "Value Field Settings". There, change it from total to average, and you should have the output you desire.

Comment: See this is the problem I am having I tried using this method but it seems to be returning the average of the absolute lowest level ie. the people rather than the average of the level above "task number"